# Debugging an ongoing .net process

Tags: .net, debugging

I have a rather annoying bug in a program I'm writing which only ever manifests itself as the program freezing when it is run *without* the debugger attached. Worker threads stay alive but the main thread freezes and windows fades the window out to white and tells me the program isn't responding.

Is there a way to attach a debugger to an ongoing .net process to discover exactly which method the main thread is frozen in?

Comment: It's a shame that as soon as I attach the debugger, the program starts working again :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the debugger using Debug > Attach to Process option.

It will list all the processes and you select your process to start debugging.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sweet move. :) I can't compete with images!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have the right edition of Visual Studio.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx