# Bugs which may be dispelled by the presence of a debugger

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I have a seriously nasty bug which I'm not having much uck tracking down. It only manifests itself as the program freezing and windows saying that the program is not responding when I run it *without* a debugger attached.

When I attach a debugger to the process from within visual studio and step through the code there is nothing untoward, and resuming execution sets the program running again, just fine, no longer frozen.

What type of bug could this possibly be which is dispelled by the very presence of a debugger?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging an ongoing .net process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157300/debugging-an-ongoing-net-process)

Comment: I deliberately kept that question about how to remote debug separate from this question about what could possibly be causing the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look out for any race conditions in your code. Setting breakpoints and stepping through the code might resolve any timing issues where one action has not yet been completed in time, but when you pause the execution, it completes in time.

Comment: I was worried someone would suggest race conditions. I suspect this is the case unfortunately, which will be... *fun* to fix

Answer (score 4):

It might not actually be locked up - it's probably that the code that is executing is running on the same thread as the UI, so it LOOKS like it's locked up.  Obviously if you're stepping through the code, you can see that it's actually doing something, but when some process is going on that freezes the UI it often appears to be locked up.

Look for extensive loops or processes that take time to complete, and try running them on a different thread and see if that takes care of it.  You can also tell if your app is actually frozen or if it's just running a long process by looking at the CPU usage in the Task Manager.

As a temporary measure, you could try to do something during loops that you suspect may be causing this by doing something to update the UI.  For example, in a WinForms application, you can add code to show where you are in the loop by adding a label and modifying the text.

For example:

```
for (each Employee currentEmployee in myEmployees)
{
   lblStatus.Text = "working on " + currentEmployee.FullName;
   Application.DoEvents();

}
```

Updating the UI this way will slow down your app because calls to Application.DoEvents are expensive, BUT it will help to assure your users that the program is not locked up (if you keep it in production) or you could choose to leave it out of the final production version and just use it while developing/testing to see how the processing is going and assure yourself that the app is not locked up.

Comment: You're right, in this case I actually know that background threads are still working, because remote processes are still receiving network communications from the "frozen" process. However, if it were stuck in a loop or waiting on a lock stepping through should reveal exactly which loop/lock it's stuck on, which it doesn't.

Comment: Using Control.Begin/Invoke or BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress too often has this effect as well.  The UI thread is flooded with invoke requests and doesn't get around to doing its normal duties anymore.  Like painting or checking input.  Calling DoEvents won't fix it, only invoking less does.

Answer (score 3):

When I run into an issue where the act of running the debugger seems to change the behavior of my application, I'll fall back to the old sneaker-net debugging method of outputting comments to a file.  This will give you great insight into the execution paths of your program and help you to identify where it may be getting stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a race condition or deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

The most common affect attaching a debugger has is timing and hence affecting race conditions which exist in the code.  This is the first thing I think of when I have a scenario where attaching a debugger changes whether or not the bug reproduces.

Here are a couple of things you can try to work around this problem.

- Try launching the process under the debugger vs. attaching
- Use WinDbg over Visual Studio.  It's a much lighter weight debugger and IME tends to affect the target process less.

Answer (score 0):

One more change in behavior without debugger attached is optimizations are enabled during JIT compile - as result lifetime of variables could be different (smaller) and some objects could be garbage collected earlier (when they are no longer accessible, which could be earlier than end of method). When you attache debugger before JIT happens this optimizations are normally disabled. (see http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/05/04/net-%e2%80%93-how-can-debugtrue-extend-the-life-time-of-local-variable/)

Advise: Attach debugger AFTER the bug happens and investigate. Collect memory dump and investigate with WinDbg if needed.